# fold and text columns

Tags: text-processing, character-encoding

Can `fold` be set to recognize characters instead of bytes? Traditional Chinese characters appear to be encoded in three bytes each (in UTF-8 at least), which means that if `fold`'s `-w` is not a multiple of three, then the following will occur:

```
$ cat in.txt
【財經中心、政治中心╱台北報導】看不慣政府施政效率緩慢，鴻海集團董事長郭台銘動念選總統！《壹週刊》報導，在川普勝選當晚，郭召集鴻海高層幹部，進行美國總統大選換人後的應變策略演練，讓人驚訝的是，郭詢問在場幹

$ cat in.txt | fold # -w is 80 by default
【財經中心、政治中心╱台北報導】看不慣政府施政效率緩��
�，鴻海集團董事長郭台銘動念選總統！《壹週刊》報導，在�
��普勝選當晚，郭召集鴻海高層幹部，進行美國總統大選換人
後的應變策略演練，讓人驚訝的是，郭詢問在場幹
```

`fold`'s default output is a width of 80 columns, and this results in 26 2/3 characters (`26 * 3 + 2`, or 80 bytes) being printed on each line. Therefore, `-w` must be set to a multiple of three in order to avoid character breakage. So, at least for `fold`, `columns=bytes`. Again, my question is, can `fold` can be set to honor multi-byte characters? The man page doesn't mention anything about this.

Comment: UTF-8 doesn't have a consistent number of bytes for each character, it uses the least number of bytes necessary to express the codepoint. for example UTF-8 only uses one byte to represent ASCII characters. In UTF-8 the leading byte conveys how many bytes will follow for the character.

Comment: So this is where big-endian and little-endian seem like they would have relevance. ... Guess that's a new research topic for tomorrow. Thanks @the_velour_fog

Comment: @RandyJosleyn This has nothing to do with endianness.

Comment: @Gilles good to know, then. I made that assumption having read something about beginning and ending character bytes a while ago. A little knowledge is a dangerous thing, I guess...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GNU fold and GNU fmt only understand bytes, not characters. To wrap to a certain number of characters, you can use sed.

```
sed 's/.\{20\}/&\n/g' <in.txt
【財經中心、政治中心╱台北報導】看不慣政
府施政效率緩慢，鴻海集團董事長郭台銘動念
選總統！《壹週刊》報導，在川普勝選當晚，
郭召集鴻海高層幹部，進行美國總統大選換人
後的應變策略演練，讓人驚訝的是，郭詢問在
場幹
```

If you wanted to break at whitespace (useful for many languages), here's a quick-and-dirty awk script.

```
awk '
    BEGIN {width = 20}
    NF == 0 {column = 0; print}
    {
        split($0, a);
        for (i in a) {
            w = length(a[i]) + 1;
            column += w;
            if (column > width) {column = w; print ""};
            if (column != w) printf " ";
            printf "%s", a[i];
        }
    }
    END {if (column) print ""}'
```

In any case make sure that your [locale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locale_(computer_software)) settings are correct. Specifically, `LC_CTYPE` must designate the right character encoding, e.g. `LC_CTYPE=en_US.utf8` or `LC_CTYPE=zh_CN.utf8` (any language code that's available on your system will do) for Unicode encoded as UTF-8.

Note that this counts characters, not screen width. Even fixed-width fonts can have double-width characters and this is typically done for Chinese characters, so e.g. a character width of 20 for the text above occupies 40 columns on typical terminals.

Answer (score 3):

If you have vim on your system (which can handle UTF-8 characters) you could try this:

insert these vim ex mode commands into a file called `fold.vim`

```
set formatoptions+=m
" uncomment and update the line below to set line width to e.g. 60 chars
" textwidth=60
normal! gqG<Esc>
wq
```

then if you have your chinese characters in a file called `chinese_chars` then you can run this from your prompt.

```
vim -e chinese_chars < fold.vim
```

where `vim -e` means start vim in "ex" mode and read in the ex commands from STDIN

#### vimscript explanation

from `:h fo-table`

> m Also break at a multi-byte character above 255.  This is useful for
>       Asian text where every character is a word on its own.

So what does that mean?

by default the `gq` command won't work on characters whose decimal number is above 255. e.g. this char: `報` has a decimal value of 22,577.
Running `set formatoptions+=m` means breaking will work with the text in `chinese_chars`.

refer:
http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/textwidth-doesn-t-work-for-Chinese-td1142655.html

For me this edits the file `chinese_chars` inplace and breaks lines at 79 or 80 chars - the default for `gq` normal mode command.